# formController validity checks undefined

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have a form with two `required` validations.  Both `$valid` and `$invalid` are always undefined.

[image: validity]

One of the validations is on a custom directive.  Here is the implementation of that (from the directives link function).

```
 scope.modelCtrl.$validators.required = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
     var value = modelValue || [];
     var valid = attrs.required && (value.length || 0) > 0;
     return valid;
 };
```

The directive has an ng-form for a dynamically added text input. The validator does get called and returns the expected values (checked in debugger).

Everything else about the validation (and the custom directive) is working as far as I can tell, but the form containing the directive is not having its validity set.

What do I need to do to get the forms values set properly?

Comment: As my experience with ngForm, I aways pass the value from the view formName.inputName.$valid to the controller at the submit to check out what I need

Comment: Random thoughts: Have you tried renaming your custom validator (in case it somehow causes issues w/the built in required validator)? Do your input tags have the `name` attribute?

Comment: @SunilD. Yeah, I gave it a different name before, but then the sitewide ng-message for 'required' validations didn't show.  Yeah, input is named.

Comment: @Fals I was trying to avoid having to check individual fields for validity in my controller, but for the time being, that's what I have resorted to